# Strange colored sqlcl results on Windows

Tags: oracle

I am trying to color the result of SQL statements with SQLcl.

I `set sqlformat ansiconsole` and execute a `select '@|red red |@' red from dual;`

The output I get looks like this:

[image]

I blame it on the Windows environment. Am I right to blame Windows and what can I do about it?

Comment: Maybe @thatjeffsmith  can help

Comment: It's is not the Windows environment. Same happens on a Linux machine.

Comment: You should report that [here] (https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/sql_developer/sqlcl)

Comment: I have posted an according question on [@thatjeffsmith's](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/ask-a-question/comment-page-3/#comment-117727) blog to which he replied he's pretty sure it's a bug. Let's see if it gets fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug, and it's fixed for the next release.

We're planning on regular, not quite monthly, updates.

Comment: Thank you for SQLcl. I only recently learned about it and am looking forward to using it.

Comment: it was just officially released about a week and a half ago, so you're not so late to the game :)